# How to find the x,y coordinates in a curve passing only the normalized position (from 0 to 1)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve

Given a curve represented by two arrays with the elements not equally spaced:

```
x = np.array([ 1.54, 0.73, 0.45, 0.25, 0.18, 0.14, 0.11, 0.10, 0.11, 0.15, 0.37, 0.74 ])
y = np.array([-1., -0.60, -0.39, -0.19, -0.10, 0.01, 0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41, 0.72, 1.])
```

And the graphic representation:

[image]

I want to find the coordinates `xi` and `yi` that correspond to the points at position `0.25`, `0.50`, `0.75`.

Is there a straingthforward way to find them in `numpy`or in `matplotlib`?

Comment: What  exactly do you mean by *ratio*? I can't figure it out from your example.

Comment: I mean the normalized position along the curve. `0` is the beginning and `1` the end...

Comment: voted to close.  Question is too vague.  There is a partial answer from tcaswell, but because OP doesn't follow-up to clarify, question is still to vague to get a meaningful answer (even though I initially upvoted this question).

Comment: @tom10 Please, don't close it because this represents a real problem. The idea came from [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17252890/832621) where I am passing to function `rtext()` the data coordinates `x,y` where I want the text to be placed. It would be better passing this normalized coordinate from `0` to `1`...

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick *some* method to interpolate your data.  If you have a model to fit your data to, use that, if not  [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation) has a bunch of tools for interpolating.

This is sort of a non-answer because the best way to do interpolation depends very much on your data and what you want to do with it.

In one sense, your question is ill-defined because say I have a function `f(t) -> (x,y)` for `t in [0, 1)`, then if I compose `f` with `g(s) -> [0, 1)`, where `g` is any monotonic function, then `f(g(s)) -> (x,y)` is *also* a valid parameterization of `(x,y)`, but `f(0.5) != f(g(0.5))`.