# Python Matplotlib Venn diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I want to plot variables that belongs to certain groups.

Say that I have 6 variables that I want to sort into these 3 groups and plot like a venn diagram. I would like to annotate the variable names into the three bubbles.
In this simple example we could say that 1 variable is in group 1, 3 variables in group 2 and 2 variables in group 3.

Could anyone help me with a simple example of how to do it in matplotlib?

Comment: How do you want to "plot" inside a Venn diagram? Do you simply want the 3 circle diagram with text labels for the different groups?

Comment: Yes thats right, the names are quite long so it would be nice to have some scaling effect for that on the bubble sizes

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is a beautiful Venn diagram add-on for matplotlib called [matplotlib-venn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib-venn). It looks like it can be completely customized to do what you are looking for, from the size of the circles (proportional to the set size), to inner and outer labels.

Using the example code on the website gives a plot like:

[image]

**Edit:** Per the comments below the following code gives non-overlapping circles with text using the same library:

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles

v = venn3(subsets=(1,1,0,1,0,0,0))
v.get_label_by_id('100').set_text('First')
v.get_label_by_id('010').set_text('Second')
v.get_label_by_id('001').set_text('Third')
plt.title("Not a Venn diagram")
plt.show()
```

Gives the diagram:

[image]

Comment: I would like to separate the bubbles though, that is no overlap

Comment: @jonas Overlap is what makes a Venn diagram, well, a Venn diagram! It shows the inter-relationship between the categories. For your sake however, it looks like you can simply make a bunch of the singular Venn diagrams and put them together how you please.

Comment: @jonas I've added an example. To be fair, I had never used to library before I started this question, I simply read the documentation. Try reading through the link provided, it may help.

Comment: @jonas Is your question "how do I draw a circle and put text in it?". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439639/matplotlib-add-circle-to-plot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252790/matplotlib-adding-text-with-more-than-one-line-adding-text-that-can-follow-the to get you started ...

Comment: The matplotlib-venn package is great but it currently has an issue that cause some sets to have a [wrong count](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/issues/23).

Comment: if you're just looking for some quick and dirty 3set or 2set venn diagram pictures, here's a collection of all 2set and 3set venn diagrams:  https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/Venn-Diagram-Pictures

Answer (score 56):

simplest way to draw venn diagrams

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C'])
set2 = set(['A', 'B', 'D'])
set3 = set(['A', 'E', 'F'])

venn3([set1, set2, set3], ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer should be scored-up for being extremely simple and effective. Outstanding!

Comment: I agree, that while extremely simple and effective, this is the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here you can just pass the arrays and the overlaps are calculated.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

def venn_diagram(a, b, c, labels=['A', 'B', 'C']):

    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    c = set(c)

    only_a = len(a - b - c)
    only_b = len(b - a - c)
    only_c = len(c - a - b)

    only_a_b = len(a & b - c)
    only_a_c = len(a & c - b)
    only_b_c = len(b & c - a)

    a_b_c = len(a & b & c)

    venn3(subsets=(only_a, only_b, only_a_b, only_c, only_a_c, only_b_c, a_b_c), set_labels=labels)

a, b, c = np.round(np.random.rand(3, 50000), 5)
venn_diagram(a, b, c)
```

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Hgx.png)

Comment: This does the job, but seems to be rather slow on large lists(~50k each).

Comment: That is a good point. You could use vectorized functions instead.