# How to isolate parts of a Venn Diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

Here is a Venn Diagram I drew in Python:

```
!pip install matplotlib_venn

from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

set1_size = 20
set2_size = 25
intersection_size = 5

venn2(subsets=(set1_size, set2_size, intersection_size))

plt.show()
```

This makes a brown part, a green part and a red part.

I want to extract the green part separately, the brown part separately and the red part separately.

Is there something that can be done to do this? I tried looking but found nothing. Is it even possible?

Or is it possible to just have the venn diagram as blank color, and then just individually highlight certain parts? Ex: center as yellow, (left circle without center) as purple, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible arguments for `.get_patch_by_id()` include '10', '11', and '01'. See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841535/python-matplotlib-venn-diagram).

See the [patch documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) for other patch parameters (e.g. color) that you can set.

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

set1_size = 20
set2_size = 25
intersection_size = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
vd = venn2(subsets=(set1_size, set2_size, intersection_size))

vd.get_patch_by_id('10').set(visible=False, label=None)
vd.get_label_by_id('10').set_text("")

vd.get_patch_by_id('11').set(visible=False, label=None)
vd.get_label_by_id('11').set_text("")

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: wow! thank you! is it possible to show the area corresponding only to the intersection?  and is it possible to show only right circle,  where the intersection is purple and the rest is green?

Comment: Comment out the lines in my code above that change the visibility of the intersection patch, and add this line: `vd.get_patch_by_id('11').set_color("purple")`. The intersection patch is referenced by `id="11"`. The left patch has `id="10"` and the right patch has `id="01"`